# How to send transactional mails from many addresses (without spamming or on behalf of)

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, symfony, swiftmailer, transactional-email

In a Laravel/Symfony SaaS app I want my clients to send out mails to their customers – my clients can manage their customer information in my app.

I am looking for a way they can send emails that are from their own addresses – and not from my domain (via `sendmail`).

These mails should not have a `on behalf of` in their `FROM`, but also I want to make sure that my service will not get gamed by spammers.

One idea was that every client can set up her own SMTP settings which `Swiftmailer` will then use to deliver the mails for each individual address. Maximum daily delivery per client should by below 500, so that might work.

Another idea was to use a service such as Amazon SES, who let you verify up to [1000 addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html). Or Sendgrid, who offer [something similar](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/can_i_send_from_multiple_from_addresses.html).

What is the most secure way to send mails from different addresses with a maximized deliverability and minimum risk of being gamed by spammers?

Answer (score 0):

For safe guarding against being marked as spam you need to

1. Have your DKIM and SPF settings in place
2. Do a [LITMUS spam test](https://litmus.com/spam-filter-tests) of your email to check your spam score against various spam check engines
3. Do domain throttling

It has nothing to do with email verification in SES because that is just a mandate for using a *From email id* while sending out emails